# What are biologically plausible ways to model binocular disparity?

Tags: vision, computational-modeling, theoretical-neuroscience

I figure there is a vast body of literature on stereovision, both neurophysiological and computational studies. Computer Vision also provides some algorithmic insight on implementing binocular disparity. Although a lot of people are doing that and have research the topic in the past, I'm lost to find a simplest/standard yet biologically plausible approach to account for binocular disparity in a neurodynamical model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Neural Mechanisms of Stereoscopic Vision](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301008298000124):
This paper is a 1998 review of the experimental data surrounding stereoscopic vision.

[Neural Encoding of Binocular Disparity: Energy Models, Position Shifts, and Phase Shifts](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~fleet/research/Papers/visRes-96.pdf):
In this paper, Heeger puts forward computational models of binocular disparity using phenomenological models of neurons (i.e., using receptive fields of neurons, not using biophysical mechanisms).

[Neural Models of Stereoscopic Vision](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016622369190043T):
A 1991 review of computational models of neural responses to binocular disparity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the references relate to the question?